# Simple Array cart dosen't display properly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have only two items(radiobtns) apple,banana , when I exceute the click event function it works properly when I console.log(cart) , However when I try to display it in a paragraph it doesnot add the new elements , why ?

```
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="appid" /><strong>apple</strong>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="banid" /><strong>banana</strong>
    <br />
    <p id="addid"><a href="#">Add to cart</a>
    </p>
    <br />
    <p id="dispid"></p>
    <script>
        var add = document.getElementById('addid');
        var app = document.getElementById('appid');
        var ban = document.getElementById('banid');
        var display = document.getElementById('dispid');
        var cart = [];
        add.addEventListener('click', function() {
          if (app.checked) {
            cart.push('apple');

          }
          else if (ban.checked) {
            cart.push('banana');
          }
          else {
            alert('please choose');
          }
        });
        display.innerHTML = 'your cart : ' + cart.toString();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Move `var cart = [];` && `display.innerHTML = 'your cart : ' + cart.toString();` inside the event handler

Comment: @Satpal this worked thanks,  but why though ?

Comment: As per your current implementation, the code `display.innerHTML ...` execute when page is loaded, never after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `addEventListener()` method attaches an event handler to the specified element.The `addEventListener()` method attaches an event handler to an element without overwriting existing event handlers.

Here `var add = document.getElementById('addid');` this elements click event is to be controlled through the event listener. So whenever there is a click event happens `add.addEventListener('click', function() {` this metho gets triggered. So whatever changes you expect need to be defined within this function.

Therefore Move  `display.innerHTML = 'your cart : ' + cart.toString();` inside your event listener function to see the  change. Plus 
Move `var cart = [];` because each time there is change variable that stores the changed value need to be reinitialized again as its a radio button one value can be chosen

```js
var add = document.getElementById('addid');
var app = document.getElementById('appid');
var ban = document.getElementById('banid');
var display = document.getElementById('dispid');

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var cart = [];
  if (app.checked) {
    cart.push('apple');

  } else if (ban.checked) {
    cart.push('banana');
  } else {
    alert('please choose');
  }
  display.innerHTML = 'your cart : ' + cart.toString();
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="test" id="appid" /><strong>apple</strong>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="test" id="banid" /><strong>banana</strong>
<br />
<p id="addid"><a href="#">Add to cart</a>
</p>
<br />
<p id="dispid"></p>
```

Comment: @Satpal I have added an explanation to my own understanding

Answer (score 2):

You should update the innerHTML inside the event listener

```
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
    display.innerHTML = 'your cart : ' + cart.toString();
})
```